# How to insert node at nth position in linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am beginner in programming. I am trying to implement linked list in java i have tried to write function to insert element at nth position but its not working properly its not showing data before that position. It may seem silly question or mistake to you but as i am beginner so your answer will be helpful and it will be appreciated.

The Code is below.

```
class Node{
int data;
Node next;
Node(){
    data=0;
    next=null;
}
}

class LinkedList{
Node head;
LinkedList(){
    head=null;
}
    
   void pushB(int item){
       Node temp=new Node();
       temp.data=item;
       temp.next=null;
        if(head==null){
        head=temp;    
        }
        else{
            temp.next=head;
            head=temp;
        }
    }
    
    void pushnth(int item, int pos){
        
     Node cur=new Node();
     cur.data=item;
     cur.next=null;
     Node temp=head;
     int i=0;
     
     while(i<pos-1){
         temp=temp.next;
         i++;
     }
     cur.next=temp;
     head=cur;
    }
    
    void print(){
        if(head==null){
            System.out.println("List empty");
        }
        
        else{
            Node temp=head;
            while(temp!=null){
                System.out.println(temp.data);
                temp=temp.next;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

public static void main(String []args) {
   System.out.println("Hello World");
   
   LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();
   
   l1.pushB(90);
   l1.pushB(80);
   l1.pushB(70);
   l1.pushB(60);
   l1.pushB(50);
   l1.pushB(30);
   l1.pushB(20);
   l1.pushB(10);
   l1.pushnth(40,4);
   l1.print();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pushnth` method changes the `head` of the list, and therefore discards all the elements before the new element.

In order to add an element at the middle of the list you have to set 2 links.

The new node should point to the next link, which you do here :

```
cur.next=temp;
```

The node that comes before `temp` should be linked to the new node. That's the part you are missing.

Something like this should work :

```
void pushnth(int item, int pos){

    Node cur=new Node();
    cur.data=item;
    Node temp=head;
    int i=0;

    while(i<pos-2){ // note that I changed the end condition
        temp=temp.next;
        i++;
    }
    // the new node is placed between temp and temp.next
    cur.next = temp.next;
    temp.next = cur;
}
```

Note that this code lacks some validations. For example, if there are too few elements in the linked list, this code will fail, so some additional checks should be added.

Comment: Thank you so much @Eran. i got it.

Comment: here we are not modifying the head but how head is giving us modified list.

Comment: @Parvez You only modify the head if you want the new node to be the first node (which you do in `pushB`). When you add an element in the middle, you modify the list by changing x.next for some node x in the list.

Comment: so here we are not even returning any list so how it is giving us the correct output as we have not modified the head and in print function we are using head which is not modified.

Comment: @Parvez Even though head wasn't modified, you changed one of the nodes in the original list to point to the new node. That changed the list.

Comment: my questions may seem silly but Eran we are declaring new Node as a temp=head and we are performing all the operation on temp so how it is affecting the head list;

Comment: @Parvez temp is not the new node in this method. cur is the new node. temp iterates over nodes in the original list (starting at head), until it reaches the position in which we want to link the new node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108629/discussion-between-parvez-and-eran).

Answer (score 0):

```
// please this is the correct add Node in position. 
public static Node addAtPosition(Node head3, int position) {
    // add node contains 0 in its data
    Node nodeAddAtPosition = new Node(1000);
    Node temp = head3;
    if (position == 0) {
        // add node contains 1000 in its data

        nodeAddAtPosition.next = head3;// assigning addFront next to head
        head3 = nodeAddAtPosition; // we need to return head assigning head to front.


    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i < position; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        nodeAddAtPosition.next = temp.next;
        temp.next = nodeAddAtPosition;


    }
    return head3;// return head
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must distinguish the case where the new item is inserted at the head of the list:

```
void pushnth(int item, int pos){

     Node cur=new Node();
     cur.data=item;
     if (pos == 0) {
         cur.next = head;
         head = cur;
     } else {
         Node temp=head;
         for (int i=1; i<pos; ++i) {
            temp=temp.next;
         }
         cur.next = temp.next;
         temp.next = cur;
      }
    }
```